# How would i loop through my JSON variable and sort them by the size of on af the variables , and keep the other tags with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I need to loop through my JSON file, where info is stored in user id's, like this.

```
{
  "350707981178109964":{"wins":1,"losses":0,"rank":4,"username":"TheeSniper95"},
  "426459326031593482":{"wins":0,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"Ding Dang Test"},
  "267752826623492102":{"wins":0,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"MrDooba"}
}
```

The long number is the user id accessed through `member.id` or `message.author.id` using the discord.js package.

I need to grab the user and put them at the top of an array with their user names and wins, the higher their wins the higher they are on the leaderboard.
But I have had trouble keeping the username with the wins. And getting the user id to access it and sort through all of them and then save it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = [];
var obj = {
  "350707981178109964": {"wins":1,"losses":0,"rank":4,"username":"TheeSniper95"},
  "42645932603159342": {"wins":0,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"Ding Dang Test"},
  "267752826623492102": {"wins":0,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"MrDooba"}
}
var  users = Object.keys(obj)
users.sort(function(a,b) {
  return obj[a].wins - obj[b].wins;
})
users.forEach(function(user) {
  var newObj = {
    user: user,
    details: obj[user]
  }
  res.push(newObj);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an array of users without their ids sorted by `wins`, you can try this:

```
let board = Object.values(users).sort((a, b) => b.wins - a.wins);
```

The `Object.values` method returns an array of object's values (which are your users) and then you sort them by `wins` in descending order using [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

If you need to include user id in your objects, you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all object's `[key, value]` pairs and them use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create an array of users with their ids included:

```js
let users = {
  "350707981178109964":{"wins":1,"losses":0,"rank":4,"username":"TheeSniper95"},
  "426459326031593482":{"wins":0,"losses":1,"rank":1,"username":"Ding Dang Test"},
  "267752826623492102":{"wins":10,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"MrDooba"},
  "267752827723492576":{"wins":3,"losses":0,"rank":1,"username":"Johny"},
  "267733277234925765":{"wins":7,"losses":4,"rank":1,"username":"Sam"}
};

let board = Object.entries(users)
              .map(([key, val]) => ({id: key, ...val}))
              .sort((a, b) => b.wins - a.wins);

console.log(board);
```

Comment: Never knew about `Object.entries` -- that's an awesome new toy. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @l3l_aze you're welcome! yes, it's quite helpful, especially with spread syntax

Comment: @SnipsYT I was glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

to sort a collection you can use underscore.js

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.sortBy(stooges, 'name');
=> [{name: 'curly', age: 60}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'moe', age: 40}];
```

Comment: Is that a npm package?

Comment: Does it have to be under the variable or can I declare it elsewhere?

Comment: just realised that was a dumb question, I can see the array in the method xD